# How to format datetime to format "2021-04-30T10:30:00+12:00" in Python?

Tags: python, datetime-format

The below code returns as format *2021-04-30 10:30:00+12:00*

```
time_now = datetime.now(timezone(settings.TIME_ZONE)).replace(microsecond=0)
```

How to get it in format *2021-04-30T10:30:00+12:00* please?

Comment: You just want to remove the T?

Comment: `now` returns a datetime object, not the string you show.  Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: No, with the T.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want -- the best I can figure out is that you want to convert the datetime object into its display string in the format you give, but then replace a particular space with the letter `T`.  If so, that is a trivial string operation.

Comment: yes, i want to get the display string in format "2021-04-30T10:30:00+12:00", I have found the below works for me: datetime.now(timezone(settings.TIME_ZONE)).replace(microsecond=0).isoformat()

Comment: Use https://strftime.org/ for transform `datetime` to `str`. You can make your own string, with the `T` where you want it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `astimezone()`. For example:

```
from datetime import datetime

time_now = datetime.now().astimezone()
my_format = time_now.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
```

`%z` is empty string if object is naive. That's why you can't print it.